# Can't make a folder in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

All I want is to make a folder at the "root" of my eclipse stuff so I can store projects from different classes together. However, it won't let me do that, the "Finish" button is greyed out until I select a parent folder - I must choose from one of the many projects I want IN this new folder. What do I do?

Comment: the root folder would be your workspace

Comment: I don't think you can put a project inside a project with Eclipse.

Comment: "store projects from different classes together" makes no sense, it is the other way around "classes from different projects together" if that is the case, create a new project, put your classes there, then import it on the projects you need.

Answer (score 1):

It kind of sounds like you'd be best served by a single project that contains all of the source files from your classes. The workspace is the root directory and any subdirectories are expected to be individual projects.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what everyone has been saying, create a project for the entire class as 1 project.  Then you can create as many classes as needed with main() and only export that single class (or dependent classes as needed) to turn in.  In addition, you could package each individual project assignment in a separate package.  As stated above, leave your root (workspace) where it is.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating multiple projects you may use Java packages option. Create a new package and put all your additional classes over there. Please note that all Java files should be under src/ directory of the eclipse project.